# Как выделить случайные ячейки в таблице Excel жёлтым цветом?

Tags: excel, vba

Задача.

1. Имеется таблица *Excel* размером 193 строки на 132 столбца.
2. Нужно в каждом столбце случайным образом выделить жёлтым цветом отдельные  ячейки.

Причём:

1. случайный выбор ячейки по каждому столбцу должен происходить независимо;
2. в каждом столбце должно быть выбрано и покрашено жёлтым цветом разное количество случайных ячеек (например, в 1-ом столбце таких ячеек должно быть выбрано случайным образом 5 штук, а во 2-ом столбце 52 штуки).

Как это сделать?

Comment: На VBS это можно реализовать довольно просто.

Comment: Какие мин и макс количества закрашенных в одном столбце? === Какой смысл в таком отображении? Всего сразу не увидеть, пролистывать долго. Какие дальнейшие действия? Может быть, красить не нужно, а, например, создать отдельный список...

Comment: Уважаемые Asidert и @vikttur, большое спасибо за ответ!

Смысл этого следующий. Нужно выделить случайным образом разное количество ячеек в разных столбцах, чтобы:
1) Знать цифры, которые в них содержатся, потом
2) Произвести их дальнейшее удаление (кстати - как это сделать одновременно,а не удалять по одному?),
3) Произвести разными способами импутацию данных (k-NN или multiple imputation),
4) Сравнить точность разных методов импутации.

Также не совсем понятно, как сравнивать импутированные значения в этих ячейках с изначальными данными, если их по всей этой таблице будет около 1000?

Comment: @Asidert, я так понимаю, что если случайным образом выделить данные из разных столбцов в отдельный список, то я не смогу произвести импутацию значений. То есть, по идее, пустые клеточки должны быть хаотично разбросаны по таблице, приблизительно повторяя характер missing data в моей основной таблице с данными, для которой я и пытаюсь выбрать наиболее подходящую технику импутации на этой опытной выборке.


Мин. и макс. количества данных в разных столбцах разные: от 1% до 50% значений.

Comment: @Александр: *их по всей этой таблице будет около 1000* - что-то мало Вы насчитали. При указанных данных практика показала - 5000-8000

Answer (score 1):

Предполагается, что диапазон начинается с ячейки *A1*. Константами задаются количество строк и столбцов диапазона, max и min процент количества выделяемых ячеек в одном столбце.

Чтобы в циклах не проверять наличие диапазона *rRng*, формируем диапазон сразу (*Set rRng = Cells(1, 1)*). Поэтому следует учитывать, что в ячейке *A1* заливка "технологическая". Для большей чистоты обработки "технологической" можно назначить ячейку вне обрабатываемого диапазона.

```
Sub RandomizeRenge()
Const lCountRows As Long = 193, lCountColumns As Long = 132
Const lMinPerc As Long = 1, lMaxPerc As Long = 50 ' кол-во: % от/до'
Dim rRng As Range
Dim lCnt As Long, lRw As Long, lQnt As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Cells(1, 1).Resize(lCountRows, lCountColumns).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    Set rRng = Cells(1, 1) ' формируем диапазон'
    Randomize

    For j = 1 To lCountColumns
        lCnt = Int(lCountRows * (Rnd() * lMaxPerc + lMinPerc) / 100) ' кол-во'
        lQnt = lQnt + lCnt ' общее кол-во'

        For i = 1 To lCnt
            lRw = Int(Rnd() * lCountRows + 1) ' случайная строка'
            Set rRng = Union(rRng, Cells(lRw, j)) ' пополняем диапазон'
        Next i
    Next j

    rRng.Interior.Color = vbYellow ' заливка ячеек'
'    rRng.ClearContents ' очистка ячеек''

    Set rRng = Nothing
    MsgBox "Выделенных ячеек в диапазоне: " & lQnt, 64, ""
End Sub
```

Процедура формирует диапазон ячеек, выбранных случайным образом. Далее с диапазоном можно проводить любые операции: красить, чистить, удалять данные, записывать, сравнивать...

При тестовом запуске  процедуры с указанными константами в диапазон записывалось от 5229 до 8173 ячеек (запуск на 100 000 итераций)

Answer (score 0):

В голову пришло такое решение. У меня есть таблица со словами, мне нужно, чтобы в каждом столбце подсвечивалось  случайное слово:

1. Для этого я в новой строке, в ячейке прописал формулу, которая записывала бы в эту ячейку случайное слово из одного столбца `=ИНДЕКС(A3:A43;СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(1;СЧЁТЗ(A3:A1227)))`.
   Где `А3:А43`" - это диапазон ячеек в котором нужно подсветить слово
   `СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(1;СЧЁТЗ(A3:A1227))` - это случайное значение от 1 до `СЧЁТЗ(A3:A1227)`,
   `СЧЁТЗ(A3:A1227)` - выдаёт общее количество заполненных словами ячеек в диапазоне `A3:A1227`. Номер ячейки 1227 я сделал таким большим, т.к. в перспективе столбцы будут дополняться. Если не будут дополняться, то диапазон можно оставить такой же, как в начале `А3:А43`.
2. Растянул эту формулу за край ячейки на остальные столбцы.
3. Применил условное форматирование для всей таблицы (подсветить повторяющиеся значения)

Т.к. в первой строке записываются значения из моей таблицы, то в таблице эти значения подсвечиваются. Затем я просто скрыл первую строку, чтобы не мешала.

[image: Подсветить случайные слова в таблице]